# Count objects in queryset by value in a field

Tags: django, django-queryset, drf-queryset

I have a queryset that is returned by the server:

```py
queryset = Item.objects.all()
ItemSerializer(queryset, many=True).data

[OrderedDict([('id', '123'), ('status', 'Available')]), 
...
OrderedDict([('id', '321'), ('status', 'Confirmed')])]
```

I can get the number of items by status:

```py
queryset.values('status').annotate(Count('status'))

<QuerySet [{'status': 'Available', 'status__count': 3}, {'status': 'Confirmed', 'status__count': 2}]>
```

As a result, I am trying to get such a response from the server:

```py
[{"id":"123","status":"Available"},
...
{"id":"321","status":"Confirmed"},
{"status": "Available", "status__count": 3}, 
{"status": "Confirmed", "status__count": 2}]
```

Comment: convert it into dict by getting first index of list

Comment: Please share Serializer class code. I think you should change response format. My suggestion  for response format- [{"id":"123","status":"Available"},
...
{"id":"321","status":"Confirmed"},
"status_stats" : [
 {"status": "Available", "status__count": 3}, 
 {"status": "Confirmed", "status__count": 2}
]
]